# How to speed up the pandas group by sample?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently picking 10% of the sample from pandas groupby and I am performing the same operation for 10 times.

```
for i in range(10):
    sampled = df.groupby(by=['month','year','id_n']).sample(frac=0.10, replace=True)
```

But each time, it is running for a very long time. Is there any alternative to make it real quick?

Thank you in advance

Comment: use numpy shuffle, with index ids

Comment: Maybe sample from your groups without executing the `groupby` method in every loop (`groups = df.groupby(by=['month', 'year', 'id_n']).groups`).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dask](https://dask.org/) .. it runs on all cores of your system

**Dask is a parallel computing library that allows us to run many computations at the same time**

- You can try [this](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html)

  - By Giving this all parameters in Client Object

    (n_workers, threads_per_worker, processes, memory_limit)